# Displaying long value within a disabled text input

Tags: html, css, input, text

I have an input field of type = "text". At the time of entering the details into the input, I can enter a long input. The value is getting stored appropriately in DB as well. After clicking on a submit button, I am disabling the field.

So input is still visible but with only the value (noneditable). The problem arises here as only the length of text box input is being displayed.

Is there any way in which the entire input will be displayed?

Comment: Post some code please? It's hard to debug when there's nothing to debug :P

Comment: Use input type = 'textarea', otherwise if you know the maximum value of your input then declare the width of the 'text' accordingly.

Comment: Yeah.. But it's not pretty unless you want to put in a bit of work.. https://jsfiddle.net/5av1zjrp/1/ `textarea` is for sure the way to go if you haven't already implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is instead of disabling the input box, you just remove the onChange event on the inout field and style the text to look like its disabled. if onChange event is something like this:

```
onChange={() => ()}
```

It won't be able to change the value of the input field, as it has an anonymous function.

That's one of way of doing it.